# How to change directory in Midnight Commander on Windows, using functions

Tags: windows, mc

In Midnight Commander (MC) on Linux, when I execute a <del>bash script</del> function (which is <del>on the $PATH</del> in .bashrc):

```
function cdtmp {
  cd /tmp
}
```

Current panel (of the MC) is changed to that location (/tmp).

In Midnight Commander on Windows, when I execute a powershell <del>script</del> function, I can see that it was executed, but MC panels stay unchanged.

I found a workaround with sending commands to mc.pipes file which works with powershell <del>, but not with batch files for me</del>. Anyway, I would like to understand the main issue and how to fix it. <del>I guess it is about using a new/separate shell on Windows vs running stuff in active/current shell on Linux.</del>

Comment: "*…on Linux, when I execute a bash script … Current panel (of the MC) is changed to that location…*: Sorry, I cannot believe that. In any multiprocess OS a script runs in a subprocess and cannot change parent process' environment. "*running stuff in active/current shell on Linux.*" How do run your scripts in the current shell instead of a subprocess?

Comment: @phd: My bad. It was not a script, but a function (in .bashrc) that changed the directory. However, the difference between Linux and Windows remains. Functions defined in powershell's profile file work outside MC, but do not affect MC.

Comment: Aha, I see, that I understand. Even `. some.sh` (source a shell script with `cd` in it) would work. No idea about Windows, never used it. 30 year ago switched from DOS to Unix. Started to use `mc` almost immediately.

Comment: I would stay with Linux if I could...
@phd: Thank you for your time and effort.